# Removing Noise From an Image

Tags: vhdl, verilog

Can anyone please help me with designing a verilog code for removing salt and pepper noise from an image.

Comment: use a median filter

Comment: Before crafting any code, Verilog or else, it is advisable to consider mathematical model or the algorithm. What is your model, pixel-by-pixel?

Comment: Depending on what else is in the image, your best bet would be to filter in the spatial=frequency (Fourier) plane prior to re-imaging. It's trivial to apply and the concepts and description are readily found, for example, in Hecht and Zajac's textbook on optics. The concept can be applied to a physical optical system, as well. But works just fine in the modern digital world.

Comment: the matrix defines the parameters for Speck size in Pixels, Sensitivity to Specks, inclusive options for specks smaller than Speck size and more aggressive recursive actions

Comment: A better question defines all the inputs and outputs as acceptance criteria, rather than a cry for help

Comment: Read [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) to ask a better questions and [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) to avoid unsuitable questions on this EE site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Salt and pepper noise is what you get when noise flips random bits in a digital image. The usual solution is to use a median-value filter, which runs a 3×3 kernel over the image, replacing the center value with the median of the 8 surrounding pixels. The median filter does a good job of preserving edges and gradients in an image while removing the errors, unlike a simple low-pass filter, which simply blurs them out along with everything else in the image. A median filter does remove fine (noise-like) detail in an image, however.

Unfortunately, finding the median value in a list of values requires sorting the list, which is not a simple operation, especially if you want to do it quickly. But you should be able to find sample code on the Internet now that you know what to look for. Matlab, Scilab, Gnu octave, scipy/numpy and other math packages have it if you want to look at a software implementation.

I have code that I developed to do this on HD video at a rate of one pixel per clock (148.5 MHz), but I'm not at liberty to share it.

On the surface, https://github.com/freecores/fpga-median appears to be close to what I did.